# SQL query not showing decimal number

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to make a SQL query that subtracts the result of one query with another query.

The first query:

```
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_ID(); 
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("Select vaegt, dato
    FROM clk_8c3944a7ef_jet_cct_vaegt
    WHERE cct_author_id=$current_user_id
    ORDER BY dato
    LIMIT 1");
    echo($result[0]->vaegt);
```

The second query:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_ID(); 
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("Select vaegt, dato
    FROM clk_8c3944a7ef_jet_cct_vaegt
    WHERE cct_author_id=$current_user_id
    ORDER BY dato DESC
    LIMIT 1");
    echo($result[0]->vaegt);
```

These two queries print out the whole number with decimals.
But the third query is supposed to print the difference between the first and the second query, which it does, but it doesn't show the decimal number:

```
function bsdk_sum_vaegt_shortcode($atts) {
    global $wpdb;
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_ID(); 
    
    $start_query = $wpdb->get_results("Select vaegt, dato
    FROM clk_8c3944a7ef_jet_cct_vaegt
    WHERE cct_author_id=$current_user_id
    ORDER BY dato
    LIMIT 1");
    
    $start_weight = $start_query[0]->vaegt;
    
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_ID(); 
    $last_query = $wpdb->get_results("Select vaegt, dato
    FROM clk_8c3944a7ef_jet_cct_vaegt
    WHERE cct_author_id=$current_user_id
    ORDER BY dato DESC
    LIMIT 1");
    
    $last_weight = $last_query[0]->vaegt;
    
    $sum = floatval(floatval($start_weight) - floatval($last_weight));
    
    return $sum;
```

I put in the floatval which I thought was supposed to show the decimal number, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: What is the datatype of `vaegt` in the database? What values are you getting from the queries? Is anything being returned, or are you getting an error?

Comment: The datatype is a String. And no I am getting the correct result on all the queries. Except that on the last one it shows the correct result (difference between first and second query), but it doesn't show the decimal number.

Comment: Could it be something on your view layer that's omitting the decimals? When I do a fiddle with your same calculation code and echo the $sum I get the decimals

Comment: For reference, I'm using this site http://phptester.net/
and this code: `function do_the_sum() {
$start_weight = 1.7534;
$last_weight = 13.49;
$sum = floatval(floatval($start_weight) - floatval($last_weight));
return $sum;
}
echo do_the_sum();`
and am getting a result of -11.7366